# C# loop numbers

Tags: c#, loops, math

I'm trying to learn a bit of programming in c# and I'd like to make a program that loops through 2 numbers and does a sum of it.

Like this:
max number is 3

1+1, 1+2, 1+3, 2+1, 2+2, 2+3, 3+1, 3+2, 3+3

I managed to do one loop ( 1+1, 1+2, 1+3) but I dont know how to do the second one so it loops every number with each.

Thank you for answers and sorry if it sounds like a dumb question, still new in c#.

Comment: Just use two loops. The second loop is the nested loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be nesting two loops:

```
int maxNumber = 3;

for(int i=1;i<=maxNumber;i++)
{
    for(int j=1;j<=maxNumber;j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", i, j, i+j);
    }
}
```

[See a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/BCUY78774)

Comment: Thank you! I did nest two loops but I made a mistake that I declared number "a" and "b" outside of loops and ++ them in each loop after each iteration and that did something terrible. Thank you for answer, this really helped out.

Comment: Glad to help :-)